# split an mysql column value into 2 columns based on REGEX

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

i have a table that looks like this

```
ID   | VALue   |
1    | Cap 120 |
1    | Sack 100 |
3    | etc.. 100 |
```

and i need to move digits in this column to a single column of its own so for above example it would be like

```
ID   | VALue    |  number |
1    | Cap  | 120     |
1    | Sack | 100     |
3    | etc..| 50      |
```

is it possible with mysql ? or do i Have to do an php solution to fix my table ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. If the format is consistent then it's certainly possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575971/mysql-split-column-into-two

Comment: can there be more than once space before the number, ex. "Cap Bap 120"?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia yes, some of it has more than one space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will handle more than one space, example "Cap Dap" (without chopping it to just "Cap")

```
select 
substring_index(value,' ',length(value) - length(replace(value, ' ', ''))) as value, 
substring_index(value,' ', -1) as num from tbl;
```

Example, with a row having more than one spaces:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9dc2f/5/0

Answer (score 2):

If there's always exactly 1 space and it's between the value and the number, then you can use the query below.

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,' ',1) as value
SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,' ',-1) as number
FROM myTable
```

Comment: Nice one, I was going to suggest string functions. +1 :)

Comment: thanks, yet it breaks when there is more than 1 space in value field

Comment: @Zalaboza you can calculate the position of the last space and use it inside the function to specify the occurrence (see my answer below)

Comment: Except for using single quotes for column aliases, this would appear to be the better answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff op's data can contain multiple spaces, so this answer doesn't work. removed the quotes